# Array as input in Laravel Form (Submit funcionality not working)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am building a form in Laravel, which receives dynamic input. The user can add a link in the input text, but can choose to add more links as desired. The funcionality for that was developing using jquery. The problem is that when I try to save the form (submit), I get this error message.

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
>   htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\jkabbas\Documents\GitProects\rastro\src\resources\views\arquiteturas\novo.blade.php)

This is the code excerpt in the laravel page, which is causing the problem. When I remove the square brackets `[]` from `name="txt-link[]"`, the error message is gone, but I need to use array because I am dealing with multiple inputs.

```html
<td>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o link da arquitetura" class="form-control" id="txt-link" name="txt-link[]" value="{{old('txt-link')}}" style="width: 730px;">
  @if($errors->has('txt-link'))
    @foreach ($errors->get('txt-link') as $message)
      <span class="help-block" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:-5px; color:rgb(170, 56, 56)">
        <b>{{  $message }}</b>
      </span>
    @endforeach  
  @endif  
</td>
```

Backend code

```php
function store(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'combo_produto'=>['not_in:0'],
        'combo_projeto'=>['not_in:0'],
        'txt-link[]'=>['required'],
    ]);
    $save_arquitetura = Arquitetura::create([
        'produto_id' =>$request['combo_produto'],
        'projeto_id' =>$request['combo_projeto'],
    ]);
    return redirect('/arquiteturas')->with('msg_success', 'Dados salvos com sucesso!'); 
}
```

Comment: please show your backend code

Comment: function store(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
  
          'combo_produto'=>['not_in:0'],
          'combo_projeto'=>['not_in:0'],
          'txt-link[]'=>['required'],
        ]);
    
          $save_arquitetura = Arquitetura::create([

            'produto_id' =>$request['combo_produto'],
            'projeto_id' =>$request['combo_projeto']
          ]);
          
          return redirect('/arquiteturas')->with('msg_success', 'Dados salvos com sucesso!');
      }

Comment: It too hard to read this code. Please add this code by edit your question

Answer (score 2):

this is caused by `value="{{old('txt-link')}}"`. Some kind of error occurred in your backend while you are uploading multiple files and your return all old input but you are not handling it here `value="{{old('txt-link')}}`. thats is the reason behind **htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**